# How to point a single spring actuator endpoint to the root ("/")

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-actuator

I have a requirement to expose a health endpoint on the root path on the specific port.

However, root path is reserved for the actuator endpoints overview and I could not find a way to overwrite that overview functionality with the specific endpoint functionality.

This DOES NOT work:

```
management.endpoints.web.base-path=/
management.endpoints.web.path-mapping.health=""
```

As a workaround, I created a rest controller which redirects "/" to "/actuator/health". But it looks ugly. Does anybody know a better solution?

Comment: you were almost there with your solution, see my answer for that 1 character you missed :D tl;dr provide `/` instead of empty string

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After conversations with multiple engineers, it seems like my solution with redirect is the only possible one.

Answer (score 0):

```
management.endpoints.web.base-path=/
management.endpoints.web.path-mapping.health=/
```

setting the `base-path` to `/` disables the discovery endpoint [as per doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.7.RELEASE/reference/html/production-ready-endpoints.html#production-ready-endpoints-hypermedia),

> When the management context path is set to /, the discovery page is disabled to prevent the possibility of a clash with other mappings.

This allows you to set the path mapping for any single actuator endpoint to `/`. You might use it for `health`, you might as well use it for any other one.

Note this is only possible when `base-path` is `/`. For any other `base-path`, trying to do `path-mapping` to `/` for any of the endpoints will give you

```
IllegalStateException: Ambiguous mapping. Cannot map 'Actuator root web endpoint' method
```

instead.